# How does the Rank Nullity Theorem work when dim(Range)>dim(Domain)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Sorry if this has been asked before.

If you have $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ where $m>n$, how does the Rank Nullity Theorem work assuming the transformation spans $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Doesn't it state that $\dim(\text{Domain}) = \dim(\text{Range}) + \dim(\text{Null})$? How does this work when $\dim(\text{Range})>\dim(\text{Domain})$?

Comment: Your assumption cannot be valid.

Comment: A consequence of the theroem is that the dimension of the range never exceeds the dimension of the domain (though you could really establish that directly, since it is easy to show that the image of a basis in the domain spans the range).

Comment: In other words, the error is that you assume that $\text{Im}(T)=\mathbb{R}^m$, but in reality, $\text{Im}(T)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\dim(\text{Im}(T))<m$.

Comment: Be careful with the meaning of *range*. Some people use it for *image*; others use it for codomain. Here we have people using it for both at once.

Comment: @cjferes If Im$(T)\subset\Bbb{R}$, doesn't that mean dim(Im$(T)) = m$? Otherwise, how is the dimension of the image defined? I must be missing something obvious

Comment: The dimension of the image is the dimension of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ consisting of the vectors of the form $T(\mathbf{x})$ as $\mathbf{x}$ ranges over all vectors in the domain, $\mathbb{R}^n$. A subspace need not have the same dimension as the ambient space, so $\mathrm{Im}(T)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ certainly does **not** mean $\dim(\mathrm{Im}(T))=m$. It means $\dim\mathrm{Im}(T))\leq m$, at best.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Would it be reasonable to say that if a matrix $A\in\Bbb{R}^{nxm}$  where $n\lt m$, some rows of A will be linearly dependent such that at most dim(Im(T))$\le$n? Although if that's true I'm still confused because I thought a linear transformation can map to higher-dimensional spaces.

Comment: If $T\colon V\to W$ is a linear transformation, $\mathrm{Im}(T) = \{T(\mathbf{v})\mid\mathbf{v}\in V\}$. The "image of $T$" is not necessarily equal to $W$ (it is $W$ if and only if $T$ is *surjective*). Is that what you are missing? Are you assuming that $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is always $W$ whenver you write $T\colon V\to W$?

Comment: An $n\times m$ matrix has $n$ rows and $m$ columns. It is not true that if there are fewer rows than columns then some rows of $A$ must be linearly dependent. An $n\times m$ matrix defines a linear tranformation from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, not one from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think you are *very* confused, and need to review the meaning of the basic terms before proceeding.

Comment: "I thought a linear transformation can map to higher-dimensional spaces".... you are still confusing the image with the codomain. Yes, a linear transformation can map *into* a space of higher dimension than the domain. But it can never map **onto** (surjectively) a space of higher dimension than the domain. That's one of the consequences of the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for noting the typo, but I cannot longer edit the comment. Indeed, I meant $\dim(\text{Im}(T))\subset\mathbb{R}^m$.